# Exclude columns from MySQL SELECT WITH ROLLUP?

Tags: mysql, rollup

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668672/mysql-with-rollup-not-showing-what-i-expected) I posed earlier, say I want to add `ID` to the query:

`SELECT client, ID, job_type, SUM(actual_value_fee) FROM jo2details GROUP BY client, job_type WITH ROLLUP`

but I don't want MySQL to try to total the `ID` column as it's an identifier for the records on the table rather than something "summable".  How can I exclude `ID` from the `WITH ROLLUP` please?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to UNION two queries. The first query will have the id and the second query will generate the subtotals. Using your example, it would look like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.client, a.job_type, sum(a.actual_value_fee)
FROM jo2details a
GROUP BY a.client, a.job_type, a.id

UNION

SELECT NULL, b.client, NULL, sum(b.actual_value_fee)
FROM jo2details b
GROUP BY b.client
WITH ROLLUP
```

From here, you'll have to play around with it to get the subtotals to sort correctly.